# jquery binding events to link fails

Tags: jquery

I have got this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').bind('click', false);
var url;
$('a').on('click',function(e){
    url=$(this).attr('href'); //;
    $('#AjaxPage').load(url+" .AjaxContent");
});
```

});

The problem is the click event works the first time .. but on the content loaded from the loaded function , the links there dont have the click event i binded .. why is that? 
I thought you use 'on' as you would use 'live'

**Update:**

Now my load function doesnt get executed:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){


$('a').bind('click', false);
    var url;


$(document).on('click', 'a',function(){
        url=$(this).attr('href'); //;
        $('#AjaxPage').load(url+" .AjaxContent");
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you do `$('a').bind('click', false);` ?

Comment: I might want to enable links programmatically by later doing this..$('a').bind('click', true); or use the unbind function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
```

with

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){ // replace document with a more precise selector if available
```

Contrary to `live`, `on` will handle events in a jQuery collection and delegates the event to the target verifying the supplied selector. The jQuery collection must be non empty. It can be more precise than `document`, of course, but must be a parent of the element you're adding and on which you wish to intercept the event.

Comment: Will using the .on() function slow down the page if it is used on `$(document)`?  I was always under the impression that you want to narrow it down as much as possible.  In your experience, does it really make much of a difference?

Comment: Yes, you want to narrow it as much as possible but this is a basic operation anyway. This is computed only when somebody clicks and it's, in practice, fast enough.

Comment: Instead of `$(document).on(..` you can narrow it down to `$('#AjaxPage').on(...`

Comment: okay,,,nevermind fixed it.. instead of this:$('a').bind('click', false);,,, I used this: e.preventdefault..although the other way was better

Comment: `e.preventdefault()` is the standard way.